# search sub-arrays with index and value to return document in solr

Tags: arrays, mongodb, elasticsearch, search, solr

I have the following data-set in the following format, and I wish it to be searchable through solr. The following example how would my each document look like.

```
{
  'key': <unique key>,
  'val_arr': [
               ['laptop', 'macbook pro', '16gb', 'i9', 'spacegrey'],
               ['cellphone', 'iPhone', '4gb', 't2', 'rose gold'],
               ['laptop', 'macbook air', '8gb', 'i5', 'black'],
               ['router', 'huawei', '10x10', 'white'],
               ['laptop', 'macbook', '8gb', 'i5', 'silve']
             ]
}
```

I would be getting search requests with Element value and its index(2 elements per request).
eg. `index1=0, val1=laptop, index2=2, val2=16gb`, that matches one of the array in the above given document, hence it pulls the whole document in search result.
I tried using the copyField and custom query parser but that would search cross-sub-arrays i.e. may fetch a laptop with 4gb phone, whereas the request could be for a 4 gb laptop. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only performing exact matches, index the values with the index as part of the value, and use a string / non-processed field type:

```
val_arr: ["0_laptop", "1_macbook pro", "2_16gb", ...]
```

That can be queried with the exact index, value combination - `val_arr:0_laptop AND val_arr:2_16gb`.

If you need to perform regular matching (and processing / tokenisation) of the field, you can use dynamic field names instead:

```
"val_arr_0": "laptop",
"val_arr_1": "macbook pro",
"val_arr_2": "16gb",
..
```

And then query the field - `val_arr_0:laptop AND val_arr_2:16gb`.

Comment: The first solution would have worked for me, but I have multiple arrays under one field. And the first values of sub-arrays could repeat. Which I guess can lead to a confusion. Searching `0_laptop` AND `2_4gb` could find these from 2 different arrays, whereas I want them to be from the same array. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Ah, I missed that part in your document, sorry! Indexing each value array as a separate document could be an easy option, instead of keeping it as several fields in one single document.

Comment: I guess that making each array a separate document is not an option for me as I need to return the whole document when matched not just one array, and that would be impossible to re-collect once broken into multiple rows.